# Can't read NFC tags properly

Tags: android, tags, nfc

every time I try to read a NFC tag I always got false from:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action))
```

I've tried with differents tags and Mifare cards but I always got the same problem.
Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Edit: Add this to your manifest.xml and It will work perfectly. The app will open everytime you read a NFC tag and It will take your Tag's ID and Tech List.

```
<intent-filter> <action
android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" /> <category
android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <data
android:mimeType="text/plain" /> </intent-filter> <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" /> <category
android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter>
```

Full Code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
 TextView textViewInfo;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     textViewInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);

     nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
     if(nfcAdapter == null){
         Toast.makeText(this,
                 "NFC NOT supported on this devices!",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
     }else if(!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()){
         Toast.makeText(this,
                 "NFC NOT Enabled!",
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
     }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

     if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
         Toast.makeText(this,
                 "onResume() - ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
         if(tag == null){
             textViewInfo.setText("tag == null");
         }else{
             String tagInfo = tag.toString() + "\n";

             tagInfo += "\nTag Id: \n";
             byte[] tagId = tag.getId();
             tagInfo += "length = " + tagId.length +"\n";
             for(int i=0; i<tagId.length; i++){
                 tagInfo += Integer.toHexString(tagId[i] & 0xFF) + " ";
             }
             tagInfo += "\n";

             String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
             tagInfo += "\nTech List\n";
             tagInfo += "length = " + techList.length +"\n";
             for(int i=0; i<techList.length; i++){
                 tagInfo += techList[i] + "\n ";
             }

             textViewInfo.setText(tagInfo);
         }
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(this,
                 "onResume() : " + action,
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

 } }
```

Comment: What intent filters did you register for your activity in the manifest?

Comment: <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>

Comment: Anyway I just managed to read the tag's ID and Tech List. Now I'm trying to read the tag's Text.
I'm quite new at this so I'm sorry if I do dumb questions.

Comment: The question is not dumb at all, it just lacks some essential information (specifically: What's the value of `action` in `onResume()`? What intent filters did you register? Did you also specify a tech-list for TECH_DISCOVERED? Do you manually start your activity or do you use an NFC tag to start it?).

Comment: I've just swapped my filters:

 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

Now, every time I read a NFC tag it opens my app and reads it perfectly

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: @t00n, since you found the solution, better to ad it as an answer